# CS50 Python - Ch 2 Conditionals

Tags: python, conditional-statements, match, cs50

I am studying CS50 for Python right now. Towards the end of chapter 2 on Conditional is a 'match' function which is used to match names of students with their respective houses (in this example, Hogwarts to Griffyindor and Slytherin members). But I can't seem to execute the code on either Google Colab or CS50 IDE. I have also referred to Python Functional Documentation and it doesn't have anything on it.

Here's the code, can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
name = input("What's your name? ")

match name:
    case "Harry":
        print("Griffyindor")
    case "Hermoine":
        print("Griffyindor")
    case "Ron":
        print("Griffyindor")
    case "Malfoy":
        print("Slytherin")
    case_:
        print("Who?")
```

Error: line 5: match name:

File "", line 5
match name:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: This syntax is only available in Python 3.10 which is the latest version - so it could be that those environments have older versions of Python.

Comment: I'm impressed that's already been incorporated into the course material. Quality!

Comment: It'd be useful to see the traceback, the exact error that you're getting - but @slothrop is probably right, here. Also, you have a few typos: it's "Hermione" and "Gryffindor". Also pt2, you could add a case for `Dobby` to be assigned to House Elf ;)

Comment: Here's the official Python documentation for this feature btw: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-match-statement

Comment: Please be more specific than "I can't seem to execute the code". (I suspect you need whitespace between "case" and "_".)

Comment: If your error is `File "", line 5 match name: ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax` then it does seem to be a version problem.  Running your code on Python 3.10, I get an error, but from a later line (the `case_` line with the missing space).

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @molbdnilo, a space is missing between the "case" and the "_". This code should work...

```py
name = input("What's your name? ")

match name:
    case "Harry":
        print("Griffyindor")
    case "Hermoine":
        print("Griffyindor")
    case "Ron":
        print("Griffyindor")
    case "Malfoy":
        print("Slytherin")
    case _:
        print("Who?")
```

Comment: There's already at least a single space between words 4 spaces of indentation for case and 8 spaces of indentation for print, exactly as per video instructions.

Comment: That code should indeed work on Python 3.10.  But OP is getting an error thrown at the `match` line, not at the `case_` line, so it appears that `match..case` doesn't work at all in that environment.

Comment: So, is it a version issue? Also, if it is, then it should work on the CS50 IDE which is the practice development environment the course provides.

Comment: @PriyaBhattacharjee Try: `import sys; print(sys.version)`.  But if the code in this answer doesn't work, it seems to be a version issue.